# How to setup a websocket in Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: websocket, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

How do I enable a port on Google Kubernetes Engine to accept websocket connections? Is there a way of doing so other than using an ingress controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web sockets are supported by Google's global load balancer, so you can use a k8s `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` to expose such a service beyond your cluster.

Do be aware that load balancers created and managed outside Kubernetes in this way will have a default connection duration of 30 seconds, which interferes with web socket operation and will cause the connection to be closed frequently. This is almost useless for web sockets to be used effectively.

Until [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/28) is resolved, you will either need to modify this timeout parameter manually, or (recommended) consider using an in-cluster ingress controller (e.g. nginx) which affords you more control.

Comment: I setup a load balancer yesterday. Once I get a bit of spare time I will play around with an ingress controller

Answer (score 1):

As per [this article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service) in the GCP documentation, there are 4 ways that you may expose a Service to external applications.

It can be exposed with a ClusterIP, a [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport), a [(TCP/UDP) Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer), or an External Name.